# Menu component in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, css, spring, jsp

I look for what components is presented on the picture, I exactly mean about menu, how to make the manu in JSP page ? It can be done with CSS, JS or what ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make simple horizontal menu using HTML & CSS. Checkout the following structure in HTML,

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in CSS

```
<style>
 ul{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
  }

 a:hover {background-color:#ff3300;}
 li {display:inline;}
</style>
```

You can find details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5).
Hope this helps you.

Comment: I pretty predict that it is some component/lib and I am look for these lib